# How to reproduce $resample and $result of 'train' object in caret?

Tags: r, regression, r-caret

I'm new to the amazing caret package and try to reproduce some of the objects from the train() output from a lm model with resampling method = 'timeslice'.

1. Why does the $result$RMSE and $result$Rsquared in my example differ
   from the output from the function defaultSummary($pred$pred, $pred$obs)?
2. What data is used to calculate RMSE, Rsquared, MAE in $resample?

   ```
   require(caret)
   require(doParallel)

   no_cores <- detectCores() - 1  
   cls = makeCluster(no_cores)
   registerDoParallel(cls)

   data(economics)
   #str(economics)
   ec.data <- as.data.frame(economics[,-1]) #drop 'date' column
   #head(ec.data)

   #trainControl() with parallel processing and 1 step forecasts by TimeSlices------------------------
   set.seed(123)
   samplesCount = nrow(ec.data)
   initialWindow  = 10
   h = 1
   s = 0
   M = 1 # no of models that are evaluated during each resample (tuning parameters)

   #seeds
   resamplesCount = length(createTimeSlices(1:samplesCount, initialWindow, horizon = h, fixedWindow = TRUE, skip = s)$test)
   seeds <- vector(mode = "list", length = resamplesCount + 1)   # length = B+1, B = number of resamples
   for(i in 1:resamplesCount) seeds[[i]] <- sample.int(1000, M)  # The first B elements of the list should be vectors of integers of >= length M where M is the number of models being evaluated for each resample.
   seeds[[(resamplesCount+1)]] <- sample.int(1000, 1) # The last element of the list only needs to be a single integer (for the final model)


   trainCtrl.ec <- trainControl(
     method = "timeslice", initialWindow = initialWindow, horizon = h, skip = s,    # data splitting
     returnResamp = "all",
     savePredictions = "all",
     seeds = seeds,
     allowParallel = TRUE)


   lm.fit.ec <- train( unemploy ~ ., data = ec.data,
                     method = "lm",
                     trControl = trainCtrl.ec)

   lm.fit.ec
   head(lm.fit.ec$resample)
   ```

Output:

```
> lm.fit.ec
Linear Regression 

574 samples
  4 predictor

No pre-processing
Resampling: Rolling Forecasting Origin Resampling (1 held-out with a fixed window) 
Summary of sample sizes: 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, ... 
Resampling results:

  RMSE     Rsquared  MAE    
  250.072  NaN       250.072

Tuning parameter 'intercept' was held constant at a value of TRUE
```

Why isn't the output for RMSE and Rsquared the same as when calculated with defaultSummary() ?

```
dat <- as.data.frame(cbind(lm.fit.ec$pred$pred, lm.fit.ec$pred$obs))
colnames(dat) <- c("pred", "obs")
defaultSummary(dat)

> defaultSummary(dat)
      RMSE   Rsquared        MAE 
394.440680   0.978365 250.072031
```

How can I reproduce the results in $resample?

```
> head(lm.fit.ec$resample)
       RMSE Rsquared       MAE intercept    Resample
1  16.33273       NA  16.33273      TRUE Training010
2 232.16184       NA 232.16184      TRUE Training011
3 197.65143       NA 197.65143      TRUE Training012
4 393.29469       NA 393.29469      TRUE Training013
5 129.99157       NA 129.99157      TRUE Training014
6  60.95649       NA  60.95649      TRUE Training015
```

Session Info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Swedish_Sweden.1252  LC_CTYPE=Swedish_Sweden.1252    LC_MONETARY=Swedish_Sweden.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=Swedish_Sweden.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] fpp_0.5             tseries_0.10-42     lmtest_0.9-35       zoo_1.8-0          
 [5] expsmooth_2.3       fma_2.3             forecast_8.2        mlbench_2.1-1      
 [9] spikeslab_1.1.5     randomForest_4.6-12 lars_1.2            doParallel_1.0.11  
[13] iterators_1.0.8     foreach_1.4.3       caret_6.0-77.9000   ggplot2_2.2.1      
[17] lattice_0.20-35
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to my questions here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/114168/how-to-get-sub-training-and-sub-test-from-cross-validation-in-caret

Q1. Why does the $result$RMSE and $result$Rsquared in my example differ from the output from the function defaultSummary($pred$pred, $pred$obs)?

A: The output from train is calculated as the average of the holdouts. In my example:

```
    # The output is the mean of $resample
    mean(lm.fit.ec$resample$RMSE)  # =250.072
    mean(lm.fit.ec$resample$MAE)   # =250.072
```

Q2. What data is used to calculate RMSE, Rsquared, MAE in $resample?

```
> head(lm.fit.ec$resample)
RMSE Rsquared       MAE intercept    Resample
1  16.33273       NA  16.33273      TRUE Training010
2 232.16184       NA 232.16184      TRUE Training011
3 197.65143       NA 197.65143      TRUE Training012
4 393.29469       NA 393.29469      TRUE Training013
5 129.99157       NA 129.99157      TRUE Training014
6  60.95649       NA  60.95649      TRUE Training015


first_holdout <- subset(lm.fit.ec$pred, Resample == "Training010")
first_holdout

> first_holdout
pred        obs rowIndex intercept    Resample
1 2756.333 2740       11      TRUE Training010  # only 1 row since 1 step forecast horizon


# Calculate RMSE, Rsquared and MAE for the holdout set
postResample(first_holdout$pred, first_holdout$obs)

> postResample(first_holdout$pred, first_holdout$obs)
RMSE     Rsquared      MAE 
16.33273       NA     16.33273
```

My confusion here was mainly caused by the fact that Rsquared was NA. But since the forcast horizon was 1 step all the hold out samples only have one row and thus no Rsquared can be calculated.