RMSE wrongly matches MAE using caret package method "timeslice" when horizon = 1 in R
Why does the linear_model RMSE match the MAE when I run the code below? The linear_model RMSE also does not match the RMSE calculated by hand.
library(caret)

e <- rnorm(750)

x <- rnorm(750, 5)

y <- 10 * x + e

model_data <- data.frame(y, x)

model_tuning <- trainControl(
  method          = "timeslice",
  initialWindow   = 36,
  horizon         = 1,
  fixedWindow     = TRUE,
  savePredictions = TRUE
)

linear_model <- train(
  form       = y ~ x,
  data       = model_data,
  method     = "lm",
  trControl  = model_tuning
)

linear_model

error <- linear_model$pred$pred - linear_model$pred$obs

sqrt(mean(error^2))

mean(abs(error))


Your time horizon is 1, meaning each test set contains a single observation. You won't be able to do calculations which rely on variance and SD as var(x) or sd(x) where x is length 1 is NA. Can you explain what you're trying to do here?

My understanding is that the result should be a time series of predicted values. Estimate the model on observations 1:36 and predict 37. Estimate on 2:37 and predict 38. Estimate on 3:38 and predict 39....The predicted values are then compared to the actual values. For a visualization please see https://topepo.github.io/caret/data-splitting.html#time.

I don't think this is time-series data, probably you should try cv or boot instead.

It's multiple time series, which caret should be able to handle.

This looks like the answer to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47297119/how-to-reproduce-resample-and-result-of-train-object-in-caret

So each resample produces an RMSE, Rsquared, and MAE. Since there is only one predicted value, the RMSE and the MAE are the same, and the Rsquared cannot be calculated. The resample$RMSE and the resample$MAE are the mean RMSE and the mean MAE across the resamples. To get the predicted versus observed statistics, the function is defaultSummary or postResample. See code below.
library(caret)

e <- rnorm(750)

x <- rnorm(750, 5)

y <- 10 * x + e

model_data <- data.frame(y, x)

model_tuning <- trainControl(
  method          = "timeslice",
  initialWindow   = 36,
  horizon         = 1,
  fixedWindow     = TRUE,
  savePredictions = TRUE
)

linear_model <- train(
  form       = y ~ x,
  data       = model_data,
  method     = "lm",
  trControl  = model_tuning
)

#These are the results from each of the resamples
linear_model

head(linear_model$resample)

mean(linear_model$resample$RMSE)

mean(linear_model$resample$MAE)

#These are the predicted versus observed statistics
predictions <- data.frame(
  pred = linear_model$pred$pred,
  obs  = linear_model$pred$obs
)

defaultSummary(predictions)

postResample(
  pred = linear_model$pred$pred,
  obs  = linear_model$pred$obs
)

error <- linear_model$pred$pred - linear_model$pred$obs

sqrt(mean(error^2))

mean(abs(error))

